# Parsing JSON in JavaScript results in SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

So I have been trying to parse JSON in javascript without success.

So printing my JSON object `body` (which I read from a server-side), it looks something like below

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "results": 
    [
        {
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I try to Parse it (see below) I always end up with the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

```
console.log('results: ', JSON.parse(body).results)
console.log('results: ', JSON.parse(body)['results'])
```

I checked similar questions here and also tried different other methods (like those below), However I always get undefined as a result.

```
console.log('results: ', body.results)
console.log('results: ', body['results'])

console.log('results: ', JSON.stringify(body).results)
console.log('results: ', JSON.stringify(body)['results'])

console.log('results: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)).results)
console.log('results: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body))['results'])
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: *"it looks something like below"* "Something like"? What does it **actually** look like? Because what you've posted is valid JSON and will not cause the error you've described.

Comment: Show `body` declaration.

Comment: Also: **What** is the unexpected token? The error tells you. For instance, is it `u` by any chance? If so, [search is your friend](/search?q=%5Bjson%5D+unexpected+token+u). More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is what is below .. only difference is I removed the all elements from the results array except for one as it was too big

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as I mentioned I already checked similar questions .. the error does not print any token (like u or others) .. just print the line and column in the line

Comment: @emed what do you mean ?

Comment: How do you get `body`? My guess it is not what you think it is.

Comment: the JSON is valid and this `JSON.parse(body).results` is the way to go and works. So the problem is elsewhere. Show us more code...

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman did you checked my answer ?

Comment: @RohitJindal thanks for your help. The issue was in the JSON I am receiving. It was build manually and have few issues. Since I am working on an existing project (not one I started from scratch) I did not assume that there is bug in JSON generation itself

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman If you think my answer is correct. please mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others as well.

Comment: @RohitJindal I think the answer might be helpful for others. However it is irrelevant to my issue as I misunderstood my problem from the very beginning.

Comment: Just to clarify, @epascarello 's guess was right on point as the code I was working on was not fully mine. I gave more details in my comment above on May 18 at 10:54.

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations :**

- As you already have `JSON object` then there is no need to parse it again.
- You can directly use `body.results` intead of `JSON.parse(body).results`.
- First try to understand both concept [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

  **DEMO**

```js
var body = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "results": 
    [
        {
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    ]
};

console.log('results: ', body.results);

for (var i in body.results) {
  console.log(body.results[i].key2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the JSON I am receiving. It was build manually and had few issues. Since I am working on an existing project (not one I started from scratch) I did not assume that there is bug in JSON generation itself.

I used [ObjectNode](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) to build my json and it worked just fine